# Error while uploading laravel app to the Internet

Tags: php, laravel

I get these errors while uploading laravel app.

```
Warning:
  require(): open_basedir restriction in effect. 
  File(/usr/home/PerQuiS/domains/www.perquis.pl/fibazy/vendor/autoload.php) 
  is not within the allowed path(s):
  (/usr/home/PerQuiS/domains/www.perquis.pl/public_html:
  /tmp:/usr/share:/usr/local/share/pear:/dev)
  in /usr/home/PerQuiS/domains/www.perquis.pl/public_html/index.php on line 24 
Warning: 
  require(/usr/home/PerQuiS/domains/www.perquis.pl /fibazy/vendor/autoload.php):
  failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in
  /usr/home/PerQuiS/domains/www.perquis.pl/public_html/index.php on line 24 
Warning:
  require(): open_basedir restriction in effect. 
  File(/usr/home/PerQuiS/domains/www.perquis.pl/fibazy/vendor/autoload.php) 
  is not within the allowed path(s):
  (/usr/home/PerQuiS/domains/www.perquis.pl/public_html: 
  /tmp:/usr/share:/usr/local/share/pear:/dev) in
  /usr/home/PerQuiS/domains/www.perquis.pl/public_html/index.php on line 24 
Warning: 
  require(/usr/home/PerQuiS/domains/www.perquis.pl/ fibazy/vendor/autoload.php):
  failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in
  /usr/home/PerQuiS/domains/www.perquis.pl/public_html/index.php on line 24 
Fatal error:
  require(): Failed opening required 
  '/usr/home/PerQuiS/domains/www.perquis.pl/public_html/.. 
  /fibazy/vendor/autoload.php'
  (include_path='.:/usr/local/share/pear') in 
  /usr/home/PerQuiS/domains/www.perquis.pl/public_html/index.php on line 24
```

Comment: Your hosting service does not allow you to load PHP code from private directories. Laravel and most other decent frameworks store most PHP code in private directories.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to open_basedir settings for this domain, set this to: `/tmp:/usr/share:/usr/local/share/pear:/dev:/usr/home/PerQuiS/domains/www.perquis.pl/`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using shared hosting you will have problems getting Laravel to work not just with the directory thing.

I would strongly recommend using laravel forge with Digital Ocean or AWS. It will save you tons of time and when it comes time to scale it will be much easier. I know that pricing will not be much more expensive and you really get what you pay for when it comes to hardware.